# I tried to create a form and style it with css but it seems like it has a margin or something like that and it does not look how it should

Tags: html, css, forms

I created a form and pot it inside a div. I want the "name" and "email" inputs to have 50% of the div's width. They should be placed on the same line.
[This is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwT2B.png)  
Here is the HTML and CSS of the form:

```
<div class="contactDiv">
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="nameInput" placeholder="name*">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="emailInput" placeholder="email*">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="message*"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>  


div .contactDiv {
    width: 700px;
    padding: 0;
}

.contactDiv input {
    height: 30px;
    color: #595959;
    font-family: gothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
}

#nameInput {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#emailInput {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

.contactDiv textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    color: #595959;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
    font-family: gothic, sans-serif;
    outline: none;

}
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ag1bsux4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have box-model issues making the widths > 50%/100%. Adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to `.contactDiv input, .contactDiv textarea` will contain padding/borders within the defined widths.

```css
div .contactDiv {
    width: 700px;
    padding: 0;
}

.contactDiv input {
    height: 30px;
    color: #595959;
    font-family: gothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    outline: none;
    margin: 0;
}

#nameInput {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#emailInput {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

.contactDiv textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    color: #595959;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
    font-family: gothic, sans-serif;
    outline: none;
}
.contactDiv input, .contactDiv textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactDiv">
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="nameInput" placeholder="name*">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="emailInput" placeholder="email*">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="message*"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fill the entire region? The email box is about 5% smaller than the total width.

Comment: @CatalinSandu awesome.

Comment: then @CatalinSandu you should flag this as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

That is because the the border-width of your input. You can set a smaller width % like 49% and will work.Or change your inputs styles to `box-sizing: border-box;` so the width will be relative to all the elements including the border. ;) or the best practice would be:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that you need to set the box-sizing: border-box; if you want to align the input boxes to allow **the default borders applied to the input boxes to be taken into account in the total width of each input**.

**CSS**

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

**CODEPEN**

http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/zNEPoW